# First visible item in listview to displace textView with simple animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-animation

I am creating a calendar. It's a fairly simple calendar with dates and events. The design requires that the calendar be a ListView wherein

```
date
     event
     event
     event
     event
     event
     event
date
     event
     event
     event
     event
     event
     event
     event
date
     event
     event
….
```

The only complication is that the top date must always be visible; it cannot scroll off the screen. Except when the next date reaches the top, it must now become the top date and remain visible until the next date in the sequence displaces it.

So for my design I have a RelativeLayout with two child views: A TextView and a ListView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F0F1F3"
    tools:context=".MyAppActivity" >

    <TextView …/>
    <ListView … />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then within `MyAppActivity.java` I use `setOnScrollListener` to track scrolling so to know when to set the value in my TextView to the top date. By using the TextView, I ensure that the top date is always visible.

But the problem is as follows. If the current top date is date1 and the next date is date2. When date2 is about to become the top date: I need to have an animation of some sort, showing date2 pushing date1 out of the way to become the top date.

I have been trying a number of stuff, such as deleting date2 when it becomes `firstVisibleItem` as I replace the value of the TextView from that of date1 to that of date2. But that approach is daunting as, if the user scrolls back he is supposed to see the previous date; etc. etc.

Does anyone know how I might get date2 to displace date1 by pushing it out of the way?

OR BETTER YET:

Is there a way to tell a listView to keep a certain item at the top of the visible items?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little overkill and resource intensive but instead of having a TextView as the "header" you can make it a ListView with the same size as the TextView would have been. The items within that ListView would be all the different dates in your calendar. Then every time you want to switch "header" dates you use something like ListViews `.smoothScrollToPosition(int pos)`. I haven't tested this or anything but it seems like a viable solution.